# How to print list items in python

Tags: python

I have written the following code:

```
def count():
    a = 1
    b = 5
    c = 2
    d = 8
    i = 0
    list1 = [a, b, c, d]
    le = len(list1)

    while (i < le):
        x = max(list1)
        print(x)
        list1.remove(x)
        i = i + 1
```

What I want to do is to print the largest number with its variable name like:

```
d:8
b:5
c:2
```

but using the above code I can only print the ascending list of numbers, not the corresponding variable names. Please suggest a way to fix this.

Comment: I don't quite get your intention. What is the difference between what you get and what you want?

Comment: You mean "I can only the the descending list without the variable names", right? And you would like to know the name of the variable. Use a dictionary instead of a list… then you can access the key

Comment: What I mean to say is that I want to print a message like :
Maximum Value d:8
Second Maximum b:5

Comment: When you have a collection of variables that you are interested in treating as the same (running through the same algorithm), it is usual for them to be in a data structure or collection. A dictionary seems reasonable here. Having them as atomic variables that are treated the same will result in some hacky code.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `dict` instead:

```
In [2]: dic=dict(a=1, b=5, c=2, d=8)

In [3]: dic
Out[3]: {'a': 1, 'b': 5, 'c': 2, 'd': 8}

In [5]: sortedKeys=sorted(dic, key=dic.get, reverse=True)

In [6]: sortedKeys
Out[6]: ['d', 'b', 'c', 'a']

In [7]: for i in sortedKeys:
   ...:     print i, dic[i]
   ...:     
d 8
b 5
c 2
a 1
```

Comment: Correct although I'm pretty sure `i` is not in the list. :-)

Comment: Thanks but the values of the variables a,b,c,d are coming from some other function, so I can not assign them values in dict

Comment: @user3288315: if you show the real code then someone might be able to show you how to get the values into a dictionary.

Comment: I would write: `for key, value in sorted(dic.iteritems()): print key, value`. This gives you the key and value in one function call (`iteritems`) and you sort them by key (`sorted`).

Comment: @hughdbrown, the OP want's to sort by value, not key. You may need `operator.itemgetter` that way.

Comment: Sorry, missed the sort by value. And the reverse-sort. Yeah, you would need `operator.itemgetter`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [OrderedDict()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

```
from collections import OrderedDict

a, b, c, d = 1, 2, 3, 6
vars = {
     'a' : a,
     'b' : b,
     'c' : c,
     'd' : d
}

d_sorted_by_value = OrderedDict(sorted(vars.items(), key=x.get, reverse=True))

for k, v in d_sorted_by_value.items():
    print "{}: {}".format(k,v)
```

List don't save variable names